# How to indirectly use a variable

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
            Dim var1 As Object = someObject
            Dim var2 As Object = anotherObject
            Dim ArrayOfObjects As Object() = {var1, var2}

            '"thing" is set to nothing, but I want var1 and var2 set to nothing
            For Each thing In ArrayOfObjects
                thing = Nothing
            Next thing
```

What I expect:

I expect it to result in

```
var1=Nothing
var2=Nothing
```

I want it to be done inside the for...next statement, because in the general case, ArrayOfObjects contains a variable number of objects, so I cannot hardcode their names.

What I get:

```
"Thing" variable is set to nothing
var1 = someObject
var2= anotherObject
```

I understand why it doesn't works. I do not know how to achieve what I want.

Comment: There should be no reason to set them to `Nothing`. Why do you think that you need that? What do you expect it to do? Maybe you are confusing it with `Dispose`. "Releasing" references is the exclusive job of the garbage collector, not yours.

Comment: All `thing = Nothing` does in the first code sample is change the value of `thing`. The collection and the objects it references will not be affected.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that you are somehow making the object `Nothing`. That's not the case. All you're doing is making a reference refer to no object. The object is still the object and any other references that refer to it still refer to it. Consider this. Let's say that I marry a women. That women has a father. She is his daughter and my wife. If I was to divorce her, in VB terms, `Me.Wife` is now `Nothing`. Does that mean that his daughter no longer exists? Of course not. She still exists and she is still his daughter. The same principle applies here.

Comment: @Richard That's why I wrote "I understand why it doesn't works"

Comment: In short, you can't achieve what you want. The only way to make a variable `Nothing` is to set that variable to `Nothing`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I'm not asking why it doesn't works. I'm asking how to make it work.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter As I explain, in the general case I don't know how many variables ArrayOfObjects has, so I cannot hardcode each one.

Comment: @yoxota: repeating myself: why you think that you need that?

Comment: `ArrayOfObjects` doesn't "have" any variables. It is an array and the array contains elements and each element is a reference to an object. Those references have absolutely no connection whatsoever to any variables. The fact that there are other variables that refer to the same objects has exactly zero relevance to the array. Again, the only way to make a variable `Nothing` is to set it to `Nothing`. Your array makes no difference to those variables and vice versa.

Comment: Why not  `Dim ArrayOfObjects As Object(2)` then `ArrayOfObjects [1]=  someObject` then `ArrayOfObjects [2] = anotherObject` then `For i=1 to 2` `ArrayOfObjects [i]=nothing` `Next`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I need that because I need to run the same code on a lot of variables stored in ArrayOfObjects. I simplify "the same code" as "thing = Nothing", to simplify the question, but instead of "thing = Nothing" I have a more complex process, and it would be bad coding to repeat "the same code" for each variable "var#"

Comment: @yoxota what prevents you from calling a method with the object in the loop?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter For example, here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Excel-get-used-rows-and-15b43cb7?redir=0 it is advised to call FinalReleaseComObject(var#) and then set var#=Nothing, but that kind of code rapidly acumulates a large number of var#, and duplicates, hardcoded, the code needed to dispose of each var#

Comment: @Tim Schmelter If there is a method that does object.me.set(Nothing), it would be fine. I don't know if such a method exists.

Comment: @yoxota: look in the link you have posted for this nethod: `Public Sub ReleaseComObject(ByVal obj As Object)`. I guess it does what you need. But even if that's microsoft code it's not necessary to set the variables to `Nothing`. It seems that the author didn't know it.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter it doesn't works. The watch window shows that the variables are not set to nothing. Doesn't even works if obj is passed ByRef.

Comment: @yoxota: there is no reason to set them to nothing as i've told you and of course it's impossible. Because the variable in a method is a different variable than the one in the loop and that's also a different variable as the first one you have used to "feed" the array. You don't need to set it to `Nothing`. A variable has a reference to the object, but it does not reference all other variables which have a reference to this object. **If you assign `Nothing` to a variable, you are _not_ modifying the object which it referred to before**:

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I don't believe is impossible. There must be a way to find the address of the variable. It is not relevant if it doesn't needs to be set to nothing, because "nothing" is just a convenient object for the example. I could the same way be asking how to make any variable =var0 instead of =Nothing

Comment: @yoxota: you still confuse variables with the objects that the variables refer. Variables are like a sign, 10km until london straight ahead. Now you change the sign, you write 10km until New York. The sign has changed but you have not changed London to New York Of course you can even  strike through London(set it to `Nothing`). Now the sign is useless, but London still exists. If you want to destroy London the correct way is to let it implement `IDisposable`(because it might contain unmanaged resources). Then call `londonVariable.Dispose()`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I do not "confuse variables with the objects that the variables refer". You confuse the point of the question, and you confuse your "I don't know" with "is impossible"

Comment: Another way of looking at it, though not strictly accurate. So you create a lot of road signs. and take photos of them. These photos are the elements of your array. Your code merely destroys the photos, not the road signs. You need to redesign the road signs so they become nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of dealing with your dilemma is to use a Collection (VB.Net has a nice range of enumerable Collections to choose from) and then create your Object when you add it to the collection. You then manage, use and reset your object from within the Collection.

VB does not have direct pointer referencing like C* has, so when you create an array or add an Object to a Collection, you are really adding a copy (and not a reference to the original object).